# How to allow users change theme for specific pages

Tags: 7, theming, panels

A page has been created with panels which list all the contents of each user.
I want to allow each user to be able to change the theme used for his own panel page.  Whenever anyone visits the user panel page,  they should see the theme of that user.

I have tried themekey but it only allows for sitewide theme.

What else can i do?

Comment: i think you have to create a custom module , and custom theme , so one theme and several set of colours , and then  in you module save by user his choice . Finally use hook_init to modify css loaded by user preference

Answer (score 1):

You hook_custom_theme()

```
function MYMODULE_custom_theme() {
  // Set path specific theme.
  if (current_path() == 'Your Path') {
    return 'Your theme name here';
  }
}
```

Note: Clear cache and have a check

Or You can use Drupal module: [ThemeKey](https://www.drupal.org/project/themekey)

> ThemeKey allows you to define simple or sophisticated theme-switching
>   rules which allow automatic selection of a theme depending on current
>   path, taxonomy terms, language, node-type, and many, many other
>   properties.

Comment: Thank you.  But this will mean the admin is setting the theme.  I want each user to be able to set their own theme for their own page

Comment: I think you are looking for a module like https://www.drupal.org/project/switchtheme and also Themekey module has 'ThemeKey User Profile' configuration, enable the option for the user to select their own themes.